# how to create the calculator using bodmas rule in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, calculator

I need to create a sample calculator on the screen like to display 3+(5*8) using bodmas rule then click the equal to display the result how can i do this any one help me

Comment: You need to be more specific - could you include some sample code or a particular part you can't work out, at the moment this reads more like a requirement than a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay for the question you have asked there is a sample code for a calculator for this requirement check [here](https://github.com/KingHenne/Calculator)

Comment: how can do this operation 3+(5*3)=18 is answer based on bodmas rule but this calculator give the result is 24.if u know any sample using bodmas rule send the tutorial link for me plz